# Filter list of tuples fast

Tags: python, list

How do I filter a list of tuples efficiently with Python based on whether the first item is the same as the third?

Suppose I have old_data and I want new_data:

```
old_data = [(2,3,2), (3,4,4), (7,6,7), (2,1,2), (5,7,2)]

new_data = [(3,4,4), (5,7,2)]
```

My current solution (list comprehension) is too slow:

```
new_data_too_slow = [x for x in old_data if x[0] != x[2]]
```

This data is many millions of rows, and I do need to return a list of tuples in the same format.

Comment: With pure Python this can't be done faster. Look at external libraries like numpy.

Comment: This is about as fast as you'll be able to get with Python, then.

Comment: How slow are you calling "too slow"? this is as fast as it goes in Python.  It may be possible to use numy to filter that, but then it will be "slow to covert your data to numpy" to start with.

Comment: I wonder if `filter` would go faster: `filter(lambda x:x[0] != x[2], old_data)`

Comment: @Robᵩ probably not, usually comprehensions are *faster*, unless you are mapping a built-in function. In any event, the difference between map/filter and equivalent list-comprehensions is usually marginal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you're using your data (this is important!) but changing to a generator may give you a performance boost.

All you have to do, is change your `[`s to `(`s.

```
new_data_too_slow = (x for x in old_data if x[0] != x[2])
```

Again, it depends on how you're using it but this method will easily outperform most IO operations. Also because it's a generator, you get one use out of it - but you will use significantly less memory.

Comment: This does have some limitations however: if you need the length up front, you're outta luck.

Comment: @Shadow, this will have less of a memory footprint but, will it actually be a faster operation?

Comment: As mentioned - it depends. We need to know more about the use-case before we know whether it'll be faster. It certainly *can* be though.

Comment: If the OP requires another, materialized list, then this will end up being slower, but, it can be faster if each filtered tuple doesn't have to be saved in a new data-structure. `new_data = [...]` seems to imply that they do...

Answer (score 0):

This could be done efficiently using `numpy` since its operations are coded in C.

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: old_data = [(2,3,2), (3,4,4), (7,6,7), (2,1,2), (5,7,2)]

In [18]: np_data = np.asarray(old_data)

In [19]: new_data = np_data[ np_data[:,0] != np_data[:,2 ] ]

In [20]: new_data
Out[20]: array([[3, 4, 4],
                [5, 7, 2]])
```

The comparison of the first and third items will be much faster this way. The conversion to `numpy` will not necessarily be expensive, because `np.asarray` (as opposed to just `np.array`) does not copy the original data unless it has to, it just wraps it.

At this point `new_data` is a `numpy` array, which you can iterate over just as if it were a list of tuples if that suffices, but you can easily turn it into a list of lists...

```
In [22]: new_data.tolist()
Out[22]: [[3, 4, 4], [5, 7, 2]]
```

...and then into a list of tuples with a list comprehension if it is really necessary for your purposes.

Here are some timings of the comparison part on some generated data with a million rows with all elements either 0 or 1.

```
In [58]: test_data = np.random.randint( 0, 2, size=(1000000,3) )

In [59]: test_data
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])

In [60]: %%timeit                                              
new_data = test_data[test_data[:,0] != test_data[:,2]]
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop

In [61]: test_data = test_data.tolist()                   

In [62]: %%timeit                                               
new_data = [ x for x in test_data if x[0] != x[2] ]
   ....: 
1 loop, best of 3: 345 ms per loop
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann Added some timings above - should have included originally.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I also tried it, got factor 7 or so (using `old_data * 10**7` as test data).